# How do I put a ClientAccessPolicy.xml file in the root directory of VS11's Local STS?

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2012, wif, clientaccesspolicy.xml, ws-trust

I am developing a Silverlight Application that uses active authentication to acquire a SAML token from an STS.  During development, I'm trying to use Visual Studio's new Local STS, but to do so I need to put a `ClientAccessPolicy.xml` in the root directory of the Local STS web application so my Silverlight app can talk to it.  Does anyone know where on my file system to put this file?

Answer (score 0):

This is quite old but maybe someone will still find it helpful.

You need to put your `ClientAccessPolicy.xml` file in the root of your **website** (not web application). So for example, if your website's physical path is `c:\inetpub\wwwroot`, you need to put your file there. See the picture below.

[image]